# I need to highlight the searched text in the React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, ecmascript-6

I need to highlight the searched text in the React application , below is my div ..

```
<div className="search-content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mattis tortor a finibus feugiat. Aliquam eu volutpat odio, et tincidunt lorem. Proin mollis erat neque, sit amet ullamcorper sem suscipit ac.
</p>
</div>
```

Im using replace function in the parent class to highlight , searchKey is the word to be highlighted . but not sure of how to replace

```
highlightedContent = (searchKey) => {
  let contentArr = document.getElementsByClassName('search-content')[0].innerHTML.replace()
}
```

Comment: Replace it with the text but wrapped in a span tag with a css class that will give it background color

Comment: Like this ?
innerHTML.replace({searchKey},<span style={{ backgroundColor:red}}>{searchKey}</span>)

Comment: Errr yeah I guess that'd work, give it a go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@rennie, Here i created a jsfillde for above query. hope it is useful. https://jsfiddle.net/Gaurav_Kumar_Rana/n5u2wwjg/258819/ hope it is useful.

```
  keyUpHandler(event){
    var searchedPara = document.querySelector('.search-content p');
    var words = event.currentTarget.value;
    var regex = RegExp(words, 'gi') // case insensitive
    var replacement = '<b>'+ words +'</b>';
    var newHTML = searchedPara.textContent.replace(regex, replacement);
    searchedPara.innerHTML = newHTML;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it works!! Thanks but I cant add styling to it

```
    var searchedPara = document.querySelector('.search-content p');
    var wordStyle={
      color:'green'
    }
    var words = searchKey;
    var regex = RegExp(words, 'gi') // case insensitive
    var replacement =`<span style=${wordStyle}>${words}</span>`
    var newHTML = searchedPara.textContent.replace(regex, replacement);
    searchedPara.innerHTML = newHTML;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

for changing background or font color. Give class to the span and then call it in css so that it will work effectively :)

`<span class="highlight">${words}</span>`

in css!

.highlight {
color: "green"
}